# std::wcout can't print out Arabic chars and some mathematical symbols

Tags: c++, windows, api, stl

Recently I want to find a general solution for `std::wcout` so that it can print out all unicode strings. but, after poking around on google, i can't find useful. I'm stuck here, anybody can help me?

`_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` won't work as expected.

Here is my current code snippet:

```
auto previousMode = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
std::wifstream wifs;
wifs.imbue(std::locale(wifs.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff,
    std::codecvt_mode(std::little_endian | std::consume_header)>));
wifs.open(L"F:\\重要网址.txt", std::ios_base::binary);

std::wstring line;
std::getline(wifs, line);

wcout << line << endl;
wifs.close();

wcout << endl;
cout << "∦" << endl;

std::wofstream wofs;
wofs.imbue(std::locale(wifs.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff,
    std::codecvt_mode(std::little_endian | std::consume_header)>));
wofs.open(L"F:\\iMoney.txt", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::ate);
wofs << line << endl;
wofs.close();
//it's important to restore mode to previous, otherwise std::cout will cause crash
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), previousMode);
```

and here is some symbols to test your solution before post here:

```
∀, ∁, ∂, ∅, ∰, ∵, ∺, ⊙, ⋾, ⋻, ⋱, ⋭, ⋣, ⋧
```

Arabic: 
لطيفة الطقس اليوم

Comment: Console font must support those characters. Try to change the font.

Comment: A standard Windows install doesn't have many fonts that can work in a console.  Fixed-pitch fonts are not that plentiful and practically any program that performs fancy typography is a GUI program.  So font-fallback cannot solve every mapping issue, some glyphs are simply not covered at all.  You will need to provide your own font.

Comment: Windows console doesn't support RTL languages. That's a pity. It means, that after installing correct font, you can print separate Arabic or Hebrew symbols, but cant write RTL text. And this is from MSDN source -"3. ...Console applications do not include text support for bi-directional languages. This is a consequence of how Windows works with console applications." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9d2b0zt.aspx)